# Getting UnsupportedHeader Bad Request (400) One of the headers specified in the request is not supported when uploading image

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Here is my code. Is there any issue in the code? Where is the problem actually? Did I miss anything? I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.18.0`;

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString);
var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(container);
await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);
```

Here are the details message.

```
One of the headers specified in the request is not supported.
RequestId:80012b75-701c-0040-5aaa-ffd8bc000000
Time:2023-10-15T20:57:42.9066248Z
Status: 400 (One of the headers specified in the request is not supported.)
ErrorCode: UnsupportedHeader

Additional Information:
HeaderName: x-ms-blob-public-access

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>UnsupportedHeader</Code><Message>One of the headers specified in the request is not supported.
RequestId:80012b75-701c-0040-5aaa-ffd8bc000000
Time:2023-10-15T20:57:42.9066248Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-public-access</HeaderName></Error>

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-error-code: UnsupportedHeader
x-ms-request-id: 80012b75-701c-0040-5aaa-ffd8bc000000
x-ms-version: 2020-10-02
x-ms-client-request-id: 83edaa76-9947-4a02-a654-1e368c711c4f
Date: Sun, 15 Oct 2023 20:57:42 GMT
Content-Length: 296
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Comment: could you try  you can try creating the container without specifying the public access type, and then modify its access level in a separate request.
   await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
   await containerClient.SetAccessPolicyAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob);

Answer (score 1):

Please check the settings of the storage account. If it is a "Premium" storage account supporting Page blobs only, then you cannot create a blob container with anonymous/blob access. The blob containers in such storage accounts are always private.